# Gradle not recognizing command "createProject"

Tags: android, javafx, gradle

I'm working with Gradle and i'd like to know why I'm getting an error:

Task createProject not found in the root directory bin.

https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Building%20and%20deploying%20JavaFX%20Applications

Did everything as said in this tutorial, even the createProject command is there but it's not working for me.
cd is set on gradle/bin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this command from the `android-tools` directory, not from `gradle/bin`.